# Infinite loop with observe in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, infinite-loop

I try to make a simulation of selection on a list of plants. This is my code in R with the lib Shiny :

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  n_pop <- reactiveVal()
  tab <- reactiveVal()
  
  S <- 0.5
  avantage_eau <- 1.1
  generation <- 0
  generation_max <- 10

  phenotype <- c("AB", "Ab", "aB", "ab")

  #Constructeur
  creer_plante <- function(type, age) {
    plante <- list(type = type, age = age)
    class(plante) <- "plante"
    return(plante)
  }

  #Getteurs
  get_type <- function(plante) {
    return(plante$type)
  }

  get_age <- function(plante) {
    return(plante$age)
  }

  #Affichage
  afficher_pheno_plantes <- function(tableau) {
    pie(table(sapply(tableau, get_type)))
  }

  afficher_age_plantes <- function(tableau) {
    pie(table(sapply(tableau, get_age)))
  }


  #Fonction
  vieillir <- function(plante) {
    return(creer_plante(get_type(plante), get_age(plante) + 1))
  }
  

  selection_nat <- function(tableau){
    tab_temp <- list()
    for (i in 1:n_pop()) {
      if (grepl("B", get_type(tableau[[i]]))) {
        if (runif(1) < S * avantage_eau) {
          tab_temp <- append(tab_temp, list(vieillir(tableau[[i]])))
        }
      } else {
        if (runif(1) < S) {
          tab_temp <- append(tab_temp, list(vieillir(tableau[[i]])))
        }
      }
    }
    return(tab_temp)
  }

  creation_tab <- function() {
    tab_temp <- list()
    for (i in 1:n_pop()) {
      nouvelle_plante <- creer_plante(phenotype[sample(1:4, 1)], 0)
      tab_temp <- append(tab_temp, list(nouvelle_plante))
    }
    return(tab_temp)
  }

  observe({
    n_pop(input$n)
    tab(creation_tab())

    t <- tab()
    while (generation < generation_max) { 
      # t <- selection_nat(t)
      n_pop(length(t))
      if (n_pop() == 0) {
        break
      }
      generation <- generation + 1
      
    }
    tab(t)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
    afficher_age_plantes(tab())
    afficher_pheno_plantes(tab())
    # cat(length(tab()), "plantes vivantes\n")
  })
}
```

I comment the line in the observe (# t <- selection_nat(t)) because I enter in a infinite loop.
Here I try to applic my fonction of selection on the value containe in t or tab().

If someone know how to help me. Thanks <3

Comment: When you use `observe({})` every reactive variable is observed. So it's normal to loop on a variable and an other one, etc, if you don't be careful about relation between events and reactive variable.  Try `observeEvent( c( reactvar1, reactvar2) ),{ bla bla})`. Since Shiny 1.6.0 there is `bindEvent`. Even with that sometimes you have also to avoid recursion with the use of `isolate()`.

Comment: At each step of `while`, the reactive variables `n_pop` and `tab` are updated, so they trigger `observe()` again and again.